# Switching back from Gnome to Unity, wiping Hard disk

Tags: unity, gnome, dd

I am new to Ubuntu. I installed 12.04, which runs Unity. I decided to try Gnome 13.10. My PC did not particularly like Gnome so I decided to switch back to Unity with a fresh re-install, hoping any issues would be eradicated. It seems to have worked okay.

My issue is the following: When reinstalling Unity after installing Gnome, it didn't recognise Gnome - instead, it thought there was no OS installed. I decided to use the "Something else" installation and removed the partitions and made three: / (15GB), swap (4GB) and /home (the rest of the space). With this in mind, I was wondering whether the Unity installation would completely remove Gnome.

Does the re-install *wipe* the disk ?

I noticed some of the other posts discussed running the LiveCD and using terminal for `dd if=dev/zero of=/dev/[hard drive name]`. So, what should I do to make sure the hard disk is *as new* ?

Reinstall Unity from the CD using the erase disk option again? Use the LiveCD terminal for some function, or do you think, despite not recognising Gnome, that the fresh reinstall is sufficient ?

Any help would be much appreciated, I found similar posts but none with this specific issue.

Comment: Unlike Windows, the swap only needs to equal your usable RAM; so, if you have 2GB of RAM, you only need 2GB for the swap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've removed the old partitioning – as you seem to have done – your old system is completely gone, including Gnome.

Deleting the old partitions and creating new ones in their place made your PC *forget* about the data on the disk, allowing it to save your new Ubuntu in its place.